# May I handle moving icon of my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible to handle the animation of moving icons in an iPhone application? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean with 'handle moving icon of my iPhone application'

Comment: I think he means when the icon is shaking and can be deleted or moved to a different spot on the home screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot. The icon motion animation is generated by iOS based on the still icon, and you have no control of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think without .gif image you can not make animated icon and ios will not support that so you have no control on it.